# How to selectivly show and hide elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Firstly please excuse the amount of code Im going to dump.

**Current Behaviour**: When you click on a li, the data-id is placed into or removed from an array and the table rows with the classes from the array are shown and all other table rows are hidden. The purpose, to filter out rows from the table that dont match the users selection.

**Problem**: If I select the location "Cannes" from ul.location and I then select "Villa" and "Hotel" from ul.propertytype I may end up showing rows in the table that are not neceserilly Villas and Hotels in Cannes, I'll get Villas and Hotels in Cannes and any other property row that contains the Villa, Hotel or Cannes classes.

**Desired Behaviour**: I want to be able to see Villas and Hotels ONLY in Cannes. Or for example, if I select "Cannes" and "Eze" from locations and "Villa" and "Hotel" from propertytypes, I only want to see Villas and Hotels in Cannes and Eze

Ive toyed with :visible selectors and foreach loops etc but this is getting a little beyond me.

**So here are my Filters**
There are 3 other filters as well but for keeping things simple I have only included 2, the others are no difference in code.

Locations (there are over 30 in the live code)

```
<ul class="location" multiple="">                   
    <li data-id="term_87" class="">Cannes</li>
    <li data-id="term_88">Cap d'Antibes &amp; Juan les Pins</li>
    <li data-id="term_133" class="">Eze</li>
</ul>
```

Property Types (there are over 30 in the live code)

```
<ul class="propertytype others" multiple="">                    
    <li data-id="villa">Villa</li>      
    <li data-id="hotel">Hotel</li>                  
    <li data-id="hotelVillas">Hotel Villas</li> 
</ul>
```

**The Table of Property Rows**
Super Simplified (over 1200 in the live code)

```
<table class="elegant_list_properties">
 <tr id="1" class="propertyrow cannes villa">
    <td>some stuff</td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="2" class="propertyrow cannes hotel">
    <td>some stuff</td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="3" class="propertyrow eze villa">
    <td>some stuff</td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="4" class="propertyrow london villa">
    <td>some stuff</td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="5" class="propertyrow paris hotel">
    <td>some stuff</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

**Example situation and desired behaviour**

If I click on the "Cannes" and "Eze" locations (ul.locations) and I click on the "Villa" and "Hotel" property types (ul.propertytype), I should only see tr#1, tr#2 and tr#3.

See below the script Im currently using and hitting a wall with.

```
//For the location filters
jQuery('.elegant_filters ul li').on('click', function(e){
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('selected');
    var filters = [];
    jQuery('.elegant_filters ul li.selected').each(function(){
        var val = jQuery(this).attr('data-id');
        filters.push('.'+val);          
    });
    console.log(filters);
    if (jQuery(filters).length < 1) {
        jQuery('.elegant_list_properties tr.propertyrow').show();
    } else {
        jQuery('.elegant_list_properties tr.propertyrow').hide();
        jQuery(filters.join(', ')).show();          
    }    
})
```

Comment: What is the relation of your location li data-id and table row? You have tried to filter the location li data-id and search for a relevant class in the table. but in the current data entered there is no such classes.

Comment: @Lasithds My apologies, I forgot to explain that I was using taxonomy term ID's for the locations values due to the varying number of special characters and spaces. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two groups (one for `locations` and other for `prototype others`) and search each `data-id` in the `<tr>`s classes (in case of `locations`, the text).

```js
$('.location li, .propertytype li').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass("selected"); //toggle the class selected, easy way to 'turn it on/off'
    showTbInfo(); //go to the function to show <tr>
});

function showTbInfo(){
    //arrays of the two <li>
    let locations = [], properties = [];
    
    //loop through <li> with .selected
    $('.location, .propertytype').find('.selected').each(function(e){
    
        //check if the <li> has .location
        if($(this).parent().hasClass('location')){ 
        
            //get the first word of tag text, in lower case
            let text = ($(this).text().indexOf(" ") > 0 ? $(this).text().substring(0, $(this).text().indexOf(" ")) : $(this).text()).toLowerCase();
            
            //add the word to locations array
            locations.push("." + text);
            
        //check if the <li> has .propertytype
        }else if($(this).parent().hasClass('propertytype')){
        
            //get the data-id attribute
            properties.push("." + $(this).data('id'));
        }
    });
  
    //if the arrays are empty, show everything
    if(locations.length <= 0 && properties.length <= 0){
        $('.elegant_list_properties tr').show();
    }else{
        //start hiding everything
        $('.elegant_list_properties tr').hide();
        
        //show every location. Example: $('.cannes, .eze').show();
        if(locations.length > 0){
            $(locations.join(", ")).show();
        }
        
        //hide every shown element that is visible but doesn't have any of the properties in .propertytype
        if(properties.length > 0){
          $('.elegant_list_properties tr:visible:not(' + properties.join(", ") + ')').hide();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="location" multiple="">                   
    <li data-id="term_87" class="">Cannes</li>
    <li data-id="term_88">Cap d'Antibes &amp; Juan les Pins</li>
    <li data-id="term_133" class="">Eze</li>
</ul>

<ul class="propertytype others" multiple="">                    
    <li data-id="villa">Villa</li>      
    <li data-id="hotel">Hotel</li>                  
    <li data-id="hotelVillas">Hotel Villas</li> 
</ul>

<table class="elegant_list_properties">
 <tr id="1" class="propertyrow cannes villa">
    <td>cannes villa</td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="2" class="propertyrow cannes hotel">
    <td>cannes hotel</td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="3" class="propertyrow eze villa">
    <td>eze villa</td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="4" class="propertyrow london villa">
    <td>london villa</td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="5" class="propertyrow paris hotel">
    <td>paris hotel</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

---

### Edit

If you need to check more  classes, there's what you can do:
Assuming you have `.agentname li`, `.bedrooms li` and `.saleorrent li`, create one array for each:

```
agentname = [], bedrooms = [], saleorrent = [];
```

In the [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function you will need to add these selectors too:

```
$('.location li.selected, .propertytype li.selected, .agentname li.selected, .bedrooms li.selected, .saleorrent li.selected').each(function(e){ //...
```

Or even:

```
$('.location, .propertytype, .agentname, .bedrooms, .saleorrent').find('.selected').each(function(e){ //...
```

After that, inside the `function(e){ }`, you need to check which array you will fill with the tag information (can use [.hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) to verify).

```
else if($(this).parent().hasClass('agentname')){ /*fill agentname array*/ }
else if($(this).parent().hasClass('bedrooms')){ /*fill bedrooms array*/ }
//to all the others
```

In the end, you check if the array is empty and use your function depending in the which `if/else` statement will be true:

```
if(/*array*/.length > 0){ /*do what you need*/ }else{ /*if array is empty*/ }
```

*Remember: if you need to check all the classes, remember to fill the arrays with the names starting by a `.`(dot), and use [.join(", ")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to return all the class names in jQuery selector.*

Comment: Hi @KL_ This solutions looks great. Can i ask, if I wanted to expand the snippet to include teh other filters: .agentname li, .bedrooms li, .saleorrent li' how would I go about that. Could you edit your solution.

Comment: You should create arrays to save `<li>` s information, then add the classes to the `$().each` function (something like `$('.bedrooms li, .saleorrent li'...)` and, inside of it, verify if he have the class you need to filter the information before insert it in the specific array.
After that, you just use the same format of the properties array treatment.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of **data-id** you can use classes. The first class group is related to **location** while the second is related to **others**.
Getting selected elements you can create two selector groups: the first in order to fetch all elements having those classes. The second in order to filter elements having also a class belonging to the second group:

```js
jQuery('.elegant_filters ul li').on('click', function (e) {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('selected');
    var filtersLocation = [];
    var filtersOthers = [];
    jQuery('.elegant_filters ul.location li.selected').each(function () {
        var val = this.textContent.toLowerCase().replace(/([\0-\x1f\x7f]|^-?\d)|^-$|[^\0-\x1f\x7f-\uFFFF\w-]/g, "\\$1");
        filtersLocation.push('.' + val);
    });
    jQuery('.elegant_filters ul.others li.selected').each(function () {
        var val = this.textContent.toLowerCase().replace(/([\0-\x1f\x7f]|^-?\d)|^-$|[^\0-\x1f\x7f-\uFFFF\w-]/g, "\\$1");
        filtersOthers.push('.' + val);
    });
    jQuery('.elegant_list_properties tr.propertyrow')
            .hide()
            .filter(filtersLocation.length > 0 ? filtersLocation.join(', ') : '*')
            .filter(filtersOthers.length > 0 ? filtersOthers.join(', ') : '*').show();
})
```

```css
.selected {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="elegant_filters">
    <ul class="location" multiple="">
        <li data-id="term_87" class="">Cannes</li>
        <li data-id="term_88">Cap d'Antibes &amp; Juan les Pins</li>
        <li data-id="term_133" class="">Eze</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="propertytype others" multiple="">
        <li data-id="villa">Villa</li>
        <li data-id="hotel">Hotel</li>
        <li data-id="hotelVillas">Hotel Villas</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<table class="elegant_list_properties">
    <tr id="1" class="propertyrow cannes villa">
        <td>....propertyrow cannes villa....</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2" class="propertyrow cannes hotel">
        <td>...propertyrow cannes hotel...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="3" class="propertyrow eze villa">
        <td>...propertyrow eze villa....</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="4" class="propertyrow london villa">
        <td>....propertyrow london villa...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="5" class="propertyrow paris hotel">
        <td>....propertyrow paris hotel...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```